# Change global settings on framebox, margin above

Tags: pdftex, packages, boxes, package-options

How do I change the global settings of framebox so that I don’t have to write `\vspace{2mm}` above every framebox I use.

```latex
\vspace{2mm}
\framebox(380,200){\textit{To be completed}}
```

Comment: You have to write this in which context? It is not the syntax used for the standard \framebox.